# GNU ARM plugin for Eclipse under Windows - OpenOCD not starting debugging

Tags: gcc, arm, eclipse-cdt, stm32f4discovery, openocd

I'm having problems trying to setup dev env for STM32F4 Discovery board in Windows.

I have installed all required files (GCC for ARM, Windows Build Tools, Eclipse Plugin) and I'm getting this error when trying to start OpenOCD debugging:

```
Missing mandatory configuration. Fill-in the 'Config options:' field in the Debugger tab.
```

This is my debug config screen:
[image]

And this is the error which I get when I try to start it (and build success message):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`openocd` must be told what kind of board it should talk to**

http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/debug/openocd/#create-the-debugger-configuration

> the only field that usually requires attention is the OpenOCD Setup
>   Other options:, where you should add one or more configuration
>   scripts; for example, for the STM32F4DISCOVERY board, the field should
>   read `-f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg`

Comment: Yes, that was that! Thanks a million!